# safari calc() left issues

Tags: css, safari, css-calc

I have a button, which is animated from right to the center of the page.

In FF and Opera it functions well. In safari it goes to the mid of the page and then jumps back to the side.

The button has the position

```
right:35px;
width: 325px;
```

Then it is animated with the destination:

```
right: 50%;
right: calc(50% - 325px/2);
right: -webkit-calc(50% - 325px/2px);
```

I got the fallback, I got the -webkit, and still it jumps back to

```
right:35px;
```

I really don't know what is wrong here..The button has .class1 with position right:35px.... on click it changes the class to .class2 with the calc-position. So in css there is nothing about 35px from the right...I am confused..

EDIT:

```js
$("#konf-menu").click(function() {
  $(".konf-button").addClass('konf-animation').removeClass('line-right');
});
```

```css
.konf-animation {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  width: 325px;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.7s;
  z-index: 1006;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  top: calc(50% + 250px);
  right: 50%;
  right: calc(50% - 325px/2);
  right: -webkit-calc(50% - 325px/2);
  animation: konfi 1.8s;
  -moz-animation: konfi 1.8s;
  -webkit-animation: konfi 1.8s;
}
@keyframes konfi {
  0% {
    right: 0px;
  }
  90% {
    right: calc(45% -325px/2);
  }
  100% {
    right: calc(50% - 325px/2);
  }
}
.line-right {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  width: 325px;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  right: 35px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.7s;
  z-index: 1006;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class=" link-underline menu-btn nav-link color-head konf hide-menu" href="#konfigurator" id="konf-menu">Konfigurator</a>

<div class="line-right konf-button">
  <div class="button-subscribe-wrap ex-modal-launcher konfig-btn">
    <button class="button-subscribe navscroll">Angebotskonfigurator</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT2: This is the momentary code. Like I said, in FF, Opera it functions like it should. In Safari 9+ it goes to its destination, and then jumps back to some place on the right. I can't find the fault. Tried it with jquery, which is even more broke, also in FF and O..

Comment: Please include full code (both HTML and CSS) that will allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Hidden Hobbes: see my edit

Comment: Thanks. I guess these tests are being run on a Mac? If so I won't be able to look into this as the Windows version of Safari is severely out dated.

Comment: yes, it is on mac. safari version 9

Comment: This is a real stab in the dark but does removing `right: -webkit-calc(50% - 162.5px);` have any effect?

Comment: I also just removed the complete right-assignement from the final class, so it just has the position from the animation "konfi", but still it jumps to the side after it reached its destination...

Comment: just edited to the newest point of state..here u can see the jumping, now to the left..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari seems to have a problem with " transition: all ".

The solution was to specifically adress the right transition-property.

Instead of

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s;
-ms-transition: all 0.7s;
-o-transition: all 0.7s;
transition: all 0.7s;
```

I now used

```
-webkit-transition: transform 0.7s;
-moz-transition: transform 0.7s;
-ms-transition: transform 0.7s;
-o-transition: transform 0.7s;
transition: transform 0.7s;
```

and everything goes fine.